# making changes to main class from subclass

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class like this :

```
class mainVC: UIViewController {

    class subVC: JSONDecodable {

        required init(json: JSON) throws {

            self.view.addSubview(myButton)

        }

    }

}
```

This is a part of code. I want to add `myButton` to the `mainVC` from `subVC` but is gives error saying :

```
Value of type 'subVC' has no member 'view'
```

and also :

```
Class declaration cannot close over value 'myButton' defined in outer scope
```

how can I do this? Thanks.

EDIT -
`myButton` has been declared inside `mainVC` (out of `subVC`)

Comment: `subVC` is not a view controller.

Comment: isn't there any way to access 'mainVC' from 'subVC' and make changes ? @the4kman

Comment: No. A class defined inside a class won't be associated with a specific instance of the enclosing class, so you have no access to any `mainVC` instances from inside `subVC`. Moreover, you should conform to the Swift naming convention, which is upper-camelCase for class names. And why are you declaring the `subVC` class inside `mainVC`?

Comment: ok thanks to response. I use TRON because of that I use a class for success and failure conditions. @DávidPásztor

Comment: To handle success/failure, you should use an enum, not a class.

Answer (score 1):

Although SubVC is contained within mainVC, it doesn't have a reference to an instance of mainVC to access its properties and methods in mainVC, so you can't directly access them. But if you wanted to do this, you could pass an instance of mainVC to your subVC.init() so that it could access such.

```
class mainVC: UIViewController {
    func foo() {print("mainVC.foo")}
    class subVC: JSONDecodable {

        required init(main:mainVC, json: JSON) throws {
            main.view.addSubview(myButton)
            main.foo()
        }
    }
}
```